# Webpack warnings on page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm getting warnings in my console when I save changes or reload my React application and its also very slow when reloading

Instead of using create-react-app, I followed along on Traversy Media's video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=deyxI-6C2u4 of setting up webpack from scratch.

It was actually working fine for the first few days but suddenly started acting very slow whenever my application reloaded after saving. These are the console warnings that display for second but then disappear once the application reloads:

```
[HMR] Cannot apply update. Need to do a full reload!
[HMR] Error: Aborted because ./src/Components/Layout/Home.js is not accepted
Update propagation: ./src/Components/Layout/Home.js -> ./src/Components/App.js -> ./src/index.js -> 0 at hotApply(http://localhost:8080/index_bundle.js:476:30) at http://localhost:8080/index.bundle.js:314:22
```

and this is what displays in my console when the application is running

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(md|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 8192
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],
}
```

I'm assuming I have to add something in my webpack file. Can somebody explain to me what I have to put in there to make my application run smoothly again? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have this warning

> Update propagation: ./src/Components/Layout/Home.js ->
>   ./src/Components/App.js -> ./src/index.js

Because you changing the the code in Home.js but Home.js is the child off App.js and App.js is child of index.js so it's kinda like nested tree. So webpack don't know how to reload your page because it's deeply nested inside 2 or 3 level of file. That is just a warning of webpack that it cant do hot reload so basically everything is working fine.

Comment: Makes sense! but I'm trying to figure out why its reloading so slow all of sudden. Like double the time it used to take a couple days ago and I haven't made any major changes to my code.. i'm just playing around with Material UI

Comment: Are you install any third party lib ? If you using a lot of third party there will be performance hit

Comment: Nope, just Material UI if you consider that a third party library. Actually now that I think about it, I did import another file called Home2.js in my App.js to test some code.. but soon after I deleted it and went back to Home.js. Is it possible, its trying to locate Home2.js in memory somewhere? I think it was around the same time I started bogging down as well.

Comment: @learnerforlife I'm not sure but to me the webpack hot reload still need some improvement when we import multi nested file. I think it's still a down side for webpack

Comment: Found my problem. I was destructuring the icons I was importing from Material UI and it was causing a drop in performance: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12422